# Create Quote by rendering Word with Visualforce

Tags: visualforce

I have been creating some Visualforce pages to create dynamic Word Docs from the Quote Object.  I am currently trying to add the Products associated to the Quote in a table, but have hit a wall.  Below is a snippet of my code to show the basics...

```
        <apex:page standardController="Quote" showHeader="false" extensions="TestMSWord" contentType="application/msWord#WK Initial Order Form.doc" cache="true">
    <html xmlns:w='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word'>
    <html xmlns:o='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office'>


    <head>
    <apex:outputText value="{!PrintView}" escape="false"/>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />

     <style>

        p.MsoFooter, li.MsoFooter, div.MsoFooter{

                mso-pagination:widow-orphan;
            }

            @page Section1{
                 size:8.5in 11.0in; 
                 mso-footer:f1; 
                 mso-paper-source:0;
            }

            div.Section1{
                 page:Section1;
            }

            table#hrdftrtbl{
                 margin:0in 0in 0in 9in;
            }  
    </style>  
    </head>

    <body>

//Page Content added

<!--Header and Footer Starts-->

    <table id='hrdftrtbl' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <!--Footer-->
                <div style='mso-element:footer' id="f1">
                    <p class="MsoFooter">
                    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
        <td align="center">
            Page <span style='mso-field-code: PAGE '></span> of <span style='mso-field-code: NUMPAGES '></span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</p>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<!--Section1 div ends-->

    </div>
    </body>  
    </html></html>
    </apex:page>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Where are you stuck? What does it do?